# How do I fit my table with images in any screen css? do i need to add a div?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

```
    

    img {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      resize: both;
    }
  <html>
    <head>
<title>Untitled-1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Untitled-1) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="901" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <img src="images/test_01.jpg" width="600" height="226" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_02.jpg" width="309" height="228" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_03.jpg" width="291" height="290" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_04.jpg" width="309" height="62" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_05.jpg" width="216" height="384" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_06.jpg" width="186" height="34" alt=""></td>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_07.jpg" width="198" height="384" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="images/test_08.jpg" width="186" height="350" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="216" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="93" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="93" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="198" height="1" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

I can't actually make the tables images fit my screen.
I tried to add a div but doesn't work
Trying to centre my table with fit width and height proportion
the width and height of my image is so big that is why im having a hard time doing a resize for the table itself to fit my screen. :( do i need to redo my design jpeg? I just literally put here one of the columns but it has many columns on it.
Everything gets screwed with my code.
I'm a beginner here. need your help.

Comment: So you want the image to fit the screen width right.?

Comment: Yah.. in proportion with the height.

Comment: So what you need the table for.? please paste the whole table structure and CSS so we can help.

Comment: hi webber.. i updated the whole table structure. its actually a whole image.. sliced into bits for links buttons etc.. when i tried to resize it using css the table breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the image resolution, and making it `width="2250" height="1010"` or even better `width="1125" height="505"`

Hope this works!

Comment: Basically resizing the image? i need to redo my design size. :( is there any other way to just code it to resize?

Comment: img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
}

when i use this code.. there are slice breaks on my tables whole image. :(

Comment: Yes, use css: `width: 25% height: 25%`

Comment: my table is just breaking.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Or instead, you could use CSS to style the size:

```
img {
    width: 25%
    height: 25%
}
```